# How to create AWS Identity Provider via the python code?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to configure authentication to AWS account via the AD creds.
In order to do that I need to create an Identity Provider. I know how to do that via the console.
[image]

But is there a way I can do that via the python code using boto3? (I do have a metadata document file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a SAML identity provider you can use the [create_saml_provider](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_saml_provider) API.

To create an OpenID connect identity provider you can use the [create_open_id_connect_provider](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_open_id_connect_provider) API.